# Como redirecionar um domínio para um subdomínio?

Tags: redirecionamento, dns

Eu tenho um site que gera sites em tempo real, cada site criado é gerado um subdomínio para acessa-lo, exemplo o funcionamento do [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com), ficando dessa forma: http://nomedousuario.meudominio.com.br.

Como faço, após contratar um novo domínio, redireciona-lo para o subdomínio que criei no gerador de sites?

Exemplo:

Criei um site e gerou o seguinte endereço: http://nomedousuario.dominio.com.br, após ter feito isso, fui no [registro.br](http://www.registro.br) e cadastrei um novo domínio chamado ***novodominio.com.br*** e preciso que ao acessa-lo seja feito um redirecionamento para o endereço http://nomedousuario.dominio.com.br porém preservando na barra de endereço o novodominio.com.br. Não confundam com redirecionamento 301.

Comment: Chegou a ver se um CNAME não resolve seu problema? Só não ter certeza se a URL será trocada.

Comment: Como faria isso via CNAME? Só consegui fazer com subdomínio e não com outros domínios.

Comment: Você registrou o `novodominio.com.br` usando um registro do tipo ADDRESS certo? Acredito que registrando ele como sendo um CNAME para `nomedousuario.dominio.com.br` vá funcionar. Só não tenho certeza sobre a questão da mudança de URL (acredito que não mude), porém não tenho como testar isso no momento.

Comment: Bom Dia. Você conseguiu criar este redirecionamento no registro.br. Estou com o mesmo problema? Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar essas linhas no sei arquivo `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^novodominio.com.br
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://nomedousuario.dominio.com.br/$1 [P]
```

Com esse código, você irá acessar o conteúdo do `http://nomedousuario.dominio.com.br`, porém o endereço exibido na barra será `novodominio.com.br`.

Outros exemplos você encontrará em [LINK](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url)